# Anemic Domain Model, CQRS, command bus

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Considering this pattern is used to support CQRS message bus, examples are [buslane Python](https://libraries.io/pypi/buslane) or [MessageBus PHP](https://github.com/SimpleBus/MessageBus)

It uses commands to change the domain model, and publishes domain events

This looks great providing the separation, and encapsulating each domain write operation on its own classes, but doesn't that make an anemic domain model ? Can a domain model be thought of a collection of services, and objects ?

Even if, doesn't that results in a domain model that is just an entity, or a data container, and all the business logic is implemented in their own command handlers.

On the contrary, if all the commands which changes the model are implemented in a class, isn't that a kind of a god class ? Or doesn't it violate SRP ?

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing apples to oranges. I think you may be either misunderstanding what the libraries to which you are referring above actually do, or you are misunderstanding DDD. Services/Commands/CommandHandlers operate at the application service "level". They are used to *coordinate* your domain and execute use cases. In this way, they provide a modularized way to interact with your domain (in contrast to scripts for example).

For example (taken directly from the docs of your latter option):

```
class RegisterUserCommandHandler
{
    ...

    public function handle(RegisterUser $command)
    {
        $user = User::register(
            $command->emailAddress(),
            $command->plainTextPassword()
        );

        $this->userRepository->add($user);
    }
}
```

The above conducts no *business* rules. As such we could imagine our `User` *domain* object like:

```
class User
{
    public static funtion register( string $emailAddress, string $plainTextPassword )
    {
        if( strlen($plainTextPassword) > 100 )
            throw new \PasswordIsTooLongException;

        ...

        DomainEvents::trigger( new UserRegistered($emailAddress) )
    }
}
```

In this way our domain is not anemic. That is, the *rules* can still be encapsulated by our domain.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a domain model be thought of a collection of services, and objects

Yes. An ADM + Services approach is actually a very good way of separating out operations where the only thing in common is the data they operate on.

ie If i have to Purchase an Order and Deliver an Order. instead of having two Order objects OrderForDelivery, OrderForPurchase etc I can have one Order with no methods and two services PurchaseService and DeliveryService.

Obviously lumping them all into one DoAnythingWithAnOrderService would be a mistake

Now You can see that the command pattern is very similar, but usually it is considered a pattern of itself

Comment: Playing Devil's Advocate, why is DoAnythingWithOrderService a mistake, but your alternative, DoAnythingWithPurchaseService, good?

Comment: why do you think thats my alternative? purchaseService is just order.purchase() moved out of order

Comment: I disagree. While ADM + Services is a way, it is not a good way. The purpose of DDD (and OOP in general) is to reduce coupling and increase cohesion. This manifests itself as the encapsulation of behavior *with* the data it acts upon. Passing "objects" into "services" tends to create an immense amount of coupling because the public surface for your "objects" must be large. It also leads to either lots of duplication or an explosion of "rules" because validation is done *around* the data instead of *with* the data.

Comment: In your example you are confusing the domain-centric view of the `Purchase` and `Deliver` operations with the application-centric view. `Order.Purchase/Deliver` would likely only change some internal `Status` of the `Order` (as one's domain is **only** responsible for conducting changes of state). The `OrderPurchased/Delivered` events raised in the process would be consumed by other contexts to actually carry-out the payment/shipment.

Comment: Though, these may very-well take the form of `Purchase/DeliverService`! The key point here is that they are *decoupled* from the `Order` (i.e. you needn't actually have the `Order` object to pay for it. Just payment details, an amount, and an `OrderId`). In this way, we can greatly simplify the system.

Comment: @king-side-slide interesting speculation, but wrong. If you program it out you will find that your OrderPurchased etc events will be virtually idendical to your Order object. The only thing you achieve is to lose the domain language of "purchasing an order" and complicate your system with needless extra classes. Your Order class will be highly coupled to your operations, requiring modification and complex validation to cover all the things you want to do to Orders

Comment: The `Order` class would require *exactly* the amount of validation required by the business rules governing the process. As such, I would expect your services to have *exactly* the same validation requirements/operations. Furthermore, as I explained above, using an ADM + services require*far* more classes to prevent duplication that couldn't exist if all the rules/operations are in one `Order` entity. Lastly, the `OrderPurchased` event would contain 3 fields: `OrderId`, `Amount`, `PaymentDetails`. `PaymentDetails` would be passed to `Order.Purchase` and `Amount` would be calculated....

Comment: That literally leaves only a *single* field overlapping between the two objects. Conveniently (and correctly), `OrderId` is a special field that needs to be passed around. I would hardly call that "virtually identical".

Comment: the order class has no validation at all. its simply data. the validation goes in the service

Comment: your event hander would have to load the order and read the extra fields off it in that case

Comment: Why would my event handler need to read data from the `Order` to pay for something? Specifically, what data? It has `Amount` and `PaymentDetails` already. You see? I think I can hear this "click" in your mind.

Comment: the list of things your purchased to put on the receipt for example. If you start leaving stuff off you only cause yourself to have to alter Order when your process changes instead of just thr handler

Comment: A receipt can be generated on `PaymentCompleted` using only the `OrderId` and `PaymentTransactionId`. Why couple everything together? The whole process musy be asyc. At any point in time a handler *could* retrieve the order and call `Order.AddReciept( paymentTransaction )`. The point is that I don't need to read the data from `Order`. "Tell don't ask"

Comment: have you looked at any recipts lately? they have to include a break down of items, tax etc etc. You dont reduce coupling with an intermediate object if its used on both sides

Comment: They **do not** have to include line items. Such a "receipt" would likely fall under your read model anyway. Right? What you are talking about is *retrieving* data. Domain models are used to *change* data. (e.g. `AddReceipt`)

Comment: What I mean is that it's irrelevant to this discussion how one extracts "receipt" information from one's database for viewing.

Comment: you can argue it out with a lawyers if you like, but the fact is that recipes generally DO contain a description of the thing you got in return for payment.

Comment: How is that relevant to this discussion? Is there some reason we can't simply query that information given my system? We are talking about how to organize a system to increase cohesion and reduce coupling.

Comment: its totally relevant. when you get the additional requirement on your purchase event to include the data you will be altering your entire system. In the ADM model I only alter the purchase service

Comment: Do I have to write fake SQL for you? Just query for the receipt!

Comment: if you query the order then you have coupled your order to your event handler and made your event pointless. You might as well have sent the whole Order to a PurchaseService

Comment: Why do I have to query the `Order`? You keep saying this, but I cannot understand specifically what part of the process I've outlined requires an `Order` query.

Comment: `Order.Purchase( paymentDetails ) -> OrderPurchased -> PaymentService.Pay( paymentDetails, amount) -> PaymentReceived -> EmailService.send( receipt )` The only place here we need to query for more data is when we *read* the receipt back. I see no problem there.

Comment: when your email service sends the receipt it needs to have turned the item data into plain text/html. so somewhere in your OrderPurchased event handler you need to hit the db to get the order back. Unless you send all the Order data in the event. If you code it out you will see ADM doesnt introduce the problems you are expecting. It will be a simplification of your event model with better seperation of concerns

Comment: You misunderstand. The `PaymentReceivedListener` only needs `OrderId` to issue a query for the receipt data to be emailed. To think an ADM simplifies a system would require an understanding that hasn’t advanced beyond scripting. I’ve coded this out in front of you and you still cannot “see” how it works!

Comment: I can see how it works. it does a query. doing the query gets the order data which I already have. Your system is over complex, doesnt scale and is highly coupled compared to the ADM version

Comment: Complexity should be understood in terms of interleaving. The event-based system I outline above has the lowest amount of coupling possible. Each event/handler is *given*  the exact minimum amount of (scalar) data it needs to operate without “asking” for that data. In fact, my system above would not need refactoring even if the `Order` class was completely removed (as no piece is aware of this entity). Your system cannot “already have” the `Order` as each step in this process must be async (which also means it scales very well). Unless... you are coupling all of your services as well...

Comment: I can’t tell if you are being disingenuous or are truly ignorant. Despite my best efforts to explain you continue to make claims which reflect almost no understanding how a well designed system should behave

Comment: Your system will require refactoring of Order the event and the handler every time a process changes, because you have split the validation, data and logic across three separate objects. You have even suggested introducing  a db query to get around refactoring the event. Rename your event to Order, add all the Order fields, rename your handler to Purchase service and put all the purchase validation and processing logic in it. Discard all your other objects

Comment: ADM "already has" the Order because you use it like an event, write it to your MQ or pass it direct to the service. its just a data struct and thus highly scaleable and decoupled

Comment: Your domain *defines* the process. If purchasing something requires new information (say `Location` for tax purposes) I would expect to need to refactor to `Order.Purchase( paymentDetails, location )`. That's the point of DDD! It's not about reducing refactoring. It's about making refactoring easy. If you draw out the dependencies of my system you will see it is a **linear chain** of `Service -> Entity -> Event <- Subscriber -> Service` where events offer async breakpoints and services are decoupled.

Comment: This makes it *easy* to refactor (replace a link). An ADM system creates a **web** where each service is dependent on other `Services` or you may loose validation. There is no difference between `OrderService.AddItem( order, item )` and `Order.AddItem( item )` except that if any other service wants to add an item, it must be dependent on `OrderService`.

Comment: That, and you can't prevent other code from changing `Order` data at a whim that may break invariants...

Comment: not true my chain is Service -> Order all the services are distinct and have no link. Don't get hung up on Order being domain language rather than CheckoutTill (PurchaseService)

Comment: Order is effectively immutable as far as a service is concerned. Change it all you like. you dont persist it after use

Comment: That's incongruous with this entire thread. This answer is in response about how to organize the pieces of a system the change the model. How does one set the `Status` of an `Order` to "Paid"? Surely there must exist services to handle changes of state (which is what you recommend in your answer).

Comment: erm, no i dont. You are trapped in a certain way of thinking. active record pattern, master rdbs, monolith applications. An Order is purchased when a purchase operation has been completed. order.status can be a calculated field. If you need it at all!

Comment: How does one record a purchase operation has been completed?

Comment: however you like. write to an audit log, update a status, send a message to the next queue in the chain. Its kind of outside the Service class's responsibility

Comment: You are talking in circles. If we need to update the `Status` to "Purchased" to indicate a purchase operation has been completed, how can we do that?

Comment: Again, this discussion is about how we manage changes of state in a system. Your advice above says to use an ADM + Services to manage changes of state (to which I responded with the common pitfalls of such an approach). The system you seem to be describing to me is simple transaction scripts wrapped in an unnecessary pseudo-OOP style.

Comment: Again, the difference between `OrderService.Purchase( order, payment, location)` and `Order.Purchase( payment, location)` is only semantic (i.e python), but can have ramifications. Because your `Order` doesn't "own" it's state (completely public surface) any other piece of code could also change it's `Status` to "Purchased". In the system I describe it is not only impossible to change the `Status` of `Order` and bypass invariants, doing so *guarantees* the kickoff of the ordering pipeline (payment -> inventory -> shipping). That makes it simpler to reason about.

Comment: why are you hung up on state changes? and such a narrow view of what they 'must' be. the question is about command pattern and CQRS. if you want to scale out effectively you have to move away from this central db idea

Comment: You have made some conflicting statements regarding how your system works. I'm asking because you have yet to clarify how you know "a purchase operation has been completed". More specifically, where does this change occur?  How can this information be known if your system never changes state? I don't have a narrow view of what a "change in state" must be. It could take many forms depending on the system. I'm asking a simple question and hand-waving (deflecting) over and over again by asserting that I'm somehow "stuck" in a certain way of thinking isn't getting us anywhere.

Comment: I listed a few ways you could record that, but ok lets take "write to an audit log" and have a simple orderEvent table where we write orderId, date, eventType. If you want to know whats occured to an order you select where orderid=x

Comment: obviously you dont do that write inside PurchaseService. You have an application listening to a MQ, reading the Order message off it, passing it to a PurchaseService instance and, writing to the audit log on completion

Comment: In fact, lets be super good and wrap the table and its read/write operations in an AuditApi to keep the concerns completely seperate.

Comment: we could add more detail, protect ourselves against double processing with a transaction, log purchase starting, purchase complete make the Audit service more generic etc etc. I don't know where you are going with this

Comment: Come on... You have just described the same architecture I outlined above, but with event sourcing (and all of the complications that it comes with). I still cannot see a compelling reason to use `PurchaseService` over `Order.Purchase`. You understand that both of these objects get the same order data regardless of how it's stored?

Comment: The only difference is that the latter doesn't require a new service every time we want to raise an event and also offers convenient place for storing a business rule like "an order cannot be purchased or delivered if it has more than 10 items". This last point is where I'm going with this (and also where I started). How would you enforce that rule without duplication?

Comment: Jeeze I said several times, its the same as the event model with less classes, less coupling and better naming. Theres no event sourcing here.

Comment: The improvement over order.purchase is that you dont just purchase orders. you have a whole tonne of unrelated operations purchase, deliver, refund, whatever. If you stick them all on order its a nightmare. You want the logic in services and the data in order

Comment: That also means the validation logic. so your 10 item limit is in the service. maybe that meams you get your error later on in the process but it means that you can change the logic without changing the world

Comment: My system requires exactly the same number of classes. You don't understand DDD. `Order.Whatever` *only* checks invariants and raises events. It's **no different** than your service. Do you not understand what I am saying when I remind you that `OrderService.Purchase(order, ...)` is only semantically different than `Order.Purchase(...)`? We are getting to the nightmare. It's the ramifications of choosing the former strategy above. Explain how you would organize that rule without duplicating the check.

Comment: where do you think the duplication occurs? I count 2 classes in my system 3 in yours + a db query

Comment: Each service requires the check no? We can adopt the same eventing/persistence model in either system (it's really not important). We both have `Order` and 2 services.

Comment: each service has the checks relevant to that service. not a duplicate of all check

Comment: whats the second service? audit?

Comment: Of course. But you if change the structure of `Order` (items are now in a different data structure) you now have to hunt down and change all services which access items and update their checks.Now add 10 more rules.... The nightmare is beginning.    `Order`, `PurchaseService`, `DeliverService`. Those are the only classes in either system assuming the save eventing/storage model.

Comment: I'm sure you can see where I'm going with this. My services are not dependent on `Order`! So not only is it clear what might need to change (which files) if such a refactoring were to occur, it would only have to be done in one spot.

Comment: Only if you have a breaking change to Order. Its a shared library and you can update as required. In your system a change to any logic requires a change to order, I only have to worry about removing fields.

Comment: But they are. your validation and the list of things you can do, plus the data structures need to do it are all embedded into order. Order.Purchase may not do all the purchasing logic, but its still there along with a dozen other methods and contains the purchase validation logic

Comment: eg the print reciept requirement, you havr to change order, the event and the hander. I just change the service

Comment: The purpose of DDD **is to isolate rules**. So YES! I *want* to have to change my `Order` when a rule changes. That makes perfect sense. My `Order` *defines* the rules. `PrintReceipt` is a read operation that only requires `OrderId` to work. Again, we can adopt the same eventing pattern in either system. I am not sure what you mean by "[everything] is embedded in the `Order`". You said your `Order` was anemic (like a struct).

Comment: but you havent isolated the rules. they are all piled together on Order Order.purchade order.deliver order.refund ... etc etc

Comment: Isolate may be the wrong word. Organize/mange is better. My services are dependent on only the public methods of `Order` (interface) instead of being dependent on it's internal structure. This is ideal.

Comment: Can you not see how this reduces coupling and makes refactoring easy? Presumably the internal state is more complex than a few method names.

Comment: Every single line of code that needs to be refactored is in one file (barring an interface change). If I need to add a rule, it can be applied in one file. If I need to change that item threshold, it can be changed in one file. This is better.

Comment: It makes it harder. You still have the data structure dependency, if order changes and gets some extra field, lets say RequestedDeliveryDate (RDD) you have to change order and any event objects with services that need the new data.

Comment: It's no harder in either system. Your services would have to change as well.

Comment: Again. We have the same eventing/persistence. They change equally.

Comment: Yup. My saving is in the logic dependency. I onyly have to chnage a single file

Comment: That's exactly wrong though... (I think you are starting to realize it). If I add another rule to `Order` that pertains to `Purchase` and `Delivery` or change the one we have, you have to change both services (two files). I only have to change `Order`.

Comment: My `Order` logic is isolated into a single place. Yours must be spread out.

Comment: you spread the logic. validation + list of services in order. data in the event. BL in the service

Comment: All business logic is in `Order`. That's the point of DDD. That's not spread out. That's "cohesive". Needing to change two services when I want to change one rule (now it's 5 items) is not cohesive. It's poor design.

Comment: woah. thats madness! I thought you were putting your main logic in the event handlers?

Comment: Define logic. That's far too abstract to understand. Business rules go in the domain (like the item threshold). Side effects go in event handlers (but calling "services" is more aligned with our system). e.g. actually paying for something. The difference is that the `PurchaseService` is invoked (via the MQ) by `Order.Purchase`.

Comment: the main logic fornpurchase would in my eyes be taking the payment. I assumed this would be  in your handler?

Comment: Dont get hung up on Order being a domain object. Till (PurchaseService) is my domain object, order is a paper form with no actions

Comment: The main logic of any system is the business rules. Actually conducting payment should be considered a "cohesive mechanism" (black box) and is outside of the core domain (every company takes payment, so this cannot be core to *your* domain). Taking the payment would be in a handler. In fact, I could likely use almost the exact same service as in your system. I just would not need any validation in the service because, by virtue of the event being raised, the operation must be valid.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to explain. A domain object is just a place to put business rules (i.e validation) so that services aren't polluted with noise (and extra coupling).

Comment: `Command -> Entity (validation) -> Event <- Subscriber -> PaymentMechanism` in contrast to `Command -> Service (validation)` where service is dependent on `Event`, `Entity` and `PaymentMechanism`.

Comment: In concrete terms it looks like: `Purchase -> Order.Purchase (validation) -> Event (persist) <- PurchaseService -> PaymentMechanism`. So validation occurs *before* any service is invoked. That is, the event may not be persisted and the service never invoked (say because the order had too many items).

Comment: Ok so you do split the logic AND have a do everything Order class. Thats _super_ coupled compared to ADM and you havent really gained anything by it. In a distributed system ADM is far superior. The data structures rarely change compared to the logic and the single responsiblity services are ideal for a microservice, update one thing without affecting others CI/CD system

Comment: You must be confused. I don't understand what you mean by "do everything". What do you think I "do" in the `Order`?  What I do *do* in the `Order` class is check invariants and raise events. That's all. That's far from *everything*. Payment is conducted via the service. This isn't complex (indeed the goal of DDD). Business logic is concentrated in a single file. This is ideal. You must be misunderstanding something here. Business logic != taking payment. Is that the disconnect? Can you see the flow above?

Comment: Your Order class has a method per service right? and logic in each method? if that logic changes you have to update that class and potentally break any of the methods. If you add a new service you need to add a new method. Anything you do to Orders gets more methods and logic in the Order class

Comment: Im not sure how you can say that taking payment isnt business logic. What methods do you accept, what are your credit limits, do you skip bank checks during sale, what fraud checks do you do etc etc

Comment: Does it not make sense that "anything you do to Orders requires changing the class"?  That's the most straightforward approach possible. The alternative is that when we change a rule (now it's 8 items) and we have to **hunt down multiple service files** to make the change. As a system grows it becomes FAR less clear where rules might need changing. Furthermore it becomes difficult to discover the rules (they are in each service). So when your coworker makes `SpecialPaymentService`, he needs to remember/know that there are rules regarding all payments in `PaymentService` that need to be copied!

Comment: What methods you accept and the like *are* business logic. They are invariants. Actually sending a request to a payment gateway (bank, paypal, stripe, whatever) is not. That's what I mean. The former list of invariants are checked in `Order.Purchase`. That actual purchasing is done in a service.

Comment: what are the multiple services you have to hunt down? If you have a specialPaymentService it will have its own uniqiue rules. When you business changes rules, only the services assocaited with those rules changes. The other services dont get touched

Comment: They are hardly invariant. Do you have all the rules for all the countries, varied methods, sale periods etc etc all in a single class?? it must changr 3 times a day and have 10 teams all working on the same file

Comment: Come on... Are you serious? The idea that there is no overlap between business rules and business processes is laughable. You are quite literally advocating for transaction scripts at this point. Here are the rules of `SpecialPaymentService` (straight from the CEO), "The same rules that apply to all other payments + {insert special rule}". How do you implement that without needing to change both payment services when a rule changes in `PaymentService`?

Comment: In the real world add like 100 more rules like that.

Comment: And no. You do not have all the rules in a single class. You have all the rules in a single domain model. That's the whole point. A domain model is a useful abstraction of the functional requirements of a system!

Comment: You are going to have to clear up what you put in order then. you said validation. "is the order purchaseable" but that depends on payment method, total value, country of sale, fraud checks etc etc. there are hundreds of lines of code and several services there and thats just one of ten similar methods on Order. For me its simple. Order has 0 methods and each service is completely separate and only has its own logic. Although of course you can split the service and have one per payment method, per country, per customer type (business/personal) etc as needed.

Comment: Ttue you have to choose whether to abstract out common rules or duplicate them. But thats hardly a new problem and not really a challenge.

Comment: Indeed my usual choice would be to duplicate. The ceo saying "the same as x" is usually followed some time later by "change the rules for x (but 'obviously' not for specialMethod)"

Comment: Indeed when the rules change your domain model changes. Of course when the rules change *any* system is going to have to be refactored in some way (it was programmed according to the rules). The central idea of DDD is to make change easy. In my example I **do not have to choose** to abstract or duplicate. Simply calling `this.Purchase()` inside `Order.SpecialPurchase` ensures the same rules are applied! If it needs to be refactored again for "obviously not specialMethod", it is easy to do so.

Comment: It took us a while, but we finally got to that nightmare: always choosing to duplicate code or increase coupling (rule abstraction). *That* is the nightmare. Where we have a directory with all of these "rules" like `UserMustBeInGoodStanding` with no idea where they actually apply (which means it can't be changed), or we have all of the rules embedded into each script so when the CEO says, "we need all purchases to handle X" you are left *searching* for what needs to be changed/fixed.

Comment: This is the exact problem that a system of transactions scripts causes! It forces either duplication or a web of coupling. We can do better! We don't have to always make that choice. We don't have to put the rules *around* the data. Grouping data *with* the rules that apply solves the problem. It solves it.

Comment: Although, that's easier said than done! (which is why we get so many questions about it here)

Comment: well I can do service.usualrules.check() or inherit too. But you have dodged the question. It sounds like your order class should be huge. where i have my business rule for various operations and types of operation each in their own service. you have all that same logic in a single object, Order

Comment: I'm sure you've heard "thin controller, fat model" before? The logic goes where it needs to be and therefore the size of a class file is exactly as big as necessary. Modularizing a system according to artificial user-imposed boundaries for aesthetics at the expense of it's behavior is silly. An `Order` may be huge. Or maybe `Order` doesn't exist at all and we have undergone "knowledge crunching" and found a more suitable model that better captures the rules (my example was a toy solution to demonstrate a problem). Given the exact rules I could generate a suitable model for any system.

Comment: well the problem with your huge order is that a single change to it affects everything. You can't limit the scope of your changes. It doesnt need to be that big. All you have to do is to change your thinking and say the Order is an immutable data struct. ie a bit if paper and your Service is the process that you apply to it. You achieve a decoupled system where a change to the purchasing rules only changes the purchasing system.

Comment: Limiting the scope is akin to limiting the rule. For example,the scope of "all purchases must now adhere to {rule}" is "all purchases". As such, the goal isn't to *limit* the scope, it is to *organize* the scope. Having more than one actor (service) in the above system that conducts a purchase would mean *both* would have to be discovered and changed. And you are correct, that *is* more decoupled. Of course the goal isn't to achieve only perfect decoupling. It's to create low coupling *and* high cohesion. This means coupling according to vectors of change (i.e "all purchases").

Comment: To clarify. Changing the logic in the `Purchase` method on `Order` does not change everything. I'm confused why you would think that. It requires the exact change as would be applied in `PurchaseService` (say refactoring 10 items to 8 items). The only state of the `Order` entity is that same data struct in your system. We are simply choosing `Order.Purchase(...)` and `Order.Deliver(...)` over `PurchaseService.Purchase(order, ...)` and `DeliveryService.Deliver(order, ...)`.

Comment: Now when we either refactor that state or change rules that extend one another (e.g. `DeliverOutOfState` and `DeliverInternational` must obey the same rules as `Deliver` plus some extra rules), we only have to change one file. We know this because we designed the system according to the rules. We recognized that the scope of "all international deliveries" and "all out of state deliveries" aren't distinct. They share the scope of "all deliveries".

Comment: And rather than having 3 distinct services with either dependencies with one another or duplication, we can simply combine them. Now we have a `DeliveryService` with 3 methods: `Deliver`, `OutOfState`, and `International` each accepting `Order` as the first arg (do you know a language where classes work like that?). What we have *discovered* is a domain entity.

Comment: If you scroll back a bit you will see i have mentioned a couple of times "Till is my domain object" The difference isnt in the split of two types of PurchaseService though. You can have two inherited services, two duplicated services or a single generic service as required. The difference is none of these services have any Delivery logic in them. Your Order object crosses domain boundaries

Comment: Simply saying it is a domain entity is of no consequence. It must *behave* as one. If you scroll back a bit farther you will see that brought emphasis multiple times to the semantics of `Order.Purchase(...)` and `OrderService.Purchase(order, ...)`. The first is far superior (which is illustrated by why python works the way it does). Coupling *files* together is the true nightmare (and the problem SOLID design seeks to avoid). It's unnecessary for services to be coupled at the file level. They can simply exist as methods.

Comment: Domain boundaries are *discovered* through analysis of the rules. If there is no reason to place `Purchase` and `Deliver` on the same object (though they share a data dependency so it seems like a logical default), `Order` can become `ShoppingCart` in the purchasing context and `Payload` in the delivery context. You see? We are modeling already!

Comment: We are now argueing about DDD rather than the origional question. But I would argue that the Domain boundaries and objects are much more related to the business stucture and language than analysys of business rules. But yes if I Place an Order with a ShoppingCart and Pay for it via a Till then ShoppingCart is PlaceOrderServuce and Till is PurchaseService.

Comment: The benefits ADM approach though really come down to the practicalities of working on large codebases. You want to silo the business rules as much as possible because the change requests come from people who understand only a small part of the overall system. They wont know the greater effects of the changes they request.

Comment: DDD is entirely about siloing (isolating) business rules away from other details in a system! That is the DDD definition of a domain model. An ADM **does not** achieve this. For example if `PurchaseService` talks to our 3rd party payment provider, then changing from using PayPal to Stripe means changing the same file as where our business rules are located. The payment provider is a *detail* so our rules are not isolated.

Comment: Furthermore, the rules for `DeliverInternational` and `Deliver` overlap and therefore cannot be in separate files (or we haven’t isolated the rules have we?). Because of the above an ADM is *terrible* for systems with lots of rules. Lastly, it is *because* stakeholders won’t know the greater effects of their changes that organizing according to organizational boundaries is often a mistake. Udin Dahan has post on this very subject.

Comment: sure it does, if you want to split the service further or add extra payment method specific classes to inject into the service thats fine. Presumably in your event model you would do a similar thing in the handler

Comment: im just replacing the event with order and moving the order method to the service

Comment: if the rules overlap you can abstract, inherit or compose in the service or services as you see fit.

Comment: the point of the adm approach is there are no greater effects. you simply dont deploy any changes to other parts of the system

Comment: I dont see how you can champion the seperation of rules whilst also saying you should have an Order class with both Purchase() and Deliver()

Comment: You are doing more than just semantic changes. A system of transaction scripts raises class methods to the file level. *This* is the fundamental problem. `Purchase` and `Deliver` are not rules. They are *processes* subject to rules. The system you describe is isolating processes not rules. In small systems this distinction may not be important (rule and process share similar boundaries). But this starts to fail when a system gets more complex because, as I have exemplified over and over again, business processes often overlap (`Deliver`/`DeliverInternational`).

Comment: Coupling services does not help (and should be avoided). For all you will have achieved is making a directory “class” with file “methods” that is much harder to reason about than a single class file.

Comment: the services are not coupled to each other. they are coupled (if you choose to couple at all)  to the shared business logic class.

Comment: lets go with your processes and rules distiction. why is it ok for you to bundle all your order rules for all order processes on a single Order class, but not ok for me to have a BaseDeliveryRules shared by two types of delivery service? It doesnt couple the two services as they both implement Deliver(Order) and can be individually decoupled at any time.

Comment: A domain entity *is* a “business logic class”. A `BaseDeliveryRules` class is just `Order` by another (worse) name. It is a fallacy that destructing a class into a directory makes things simpler (that is a collection of `Service` and `Rule` classes). It increases coupling for no benefit. “Simple” must be understood in terms of interleaving. It is therefore *simpler* to group all the rules into one “shared business logic class”. Doing so results in a domain model. The lowest amount of coupling possible (while still maintainable) is the system I outline above with `Entity -> Event <- Service`.

Comment: how can you say grouping the logic results in less coupling? you cant get more tightly coupled than puting the methods in the same class

Comment: I challenge you to code it out both ways and compare. I did it a while back, one of my questions mught still exist

Comment: Each service must be coupled to each rule that applies to the process for which it governs. If each rule is its own file, that can mean coupling between many files. Grouping more rules into a single file is simply moving closer to the system for which I am advocating. Separating responsibilities further and moving the rules and services into their own packages yields the exact system for which I am advocating.

Comment: The difference between the two systems is clear. you have a classic oop Order class with multiple process methods and logic. I have a method free Order struct with methods seperated into services. Athough you are free to further abstract and share the logic in similar services if you wish you will never have a BL class which crosses process boundarys. Nor will you have an Event struct betweeb Order and the Service. The ADM pattern has demostrably less coupling regardless of how you structure the services

Comment: further more. if you tried to strictly follow your pattern in a larger system your Order class woild become unmanagbley large

Comment: I’m still not convinced you understand a DDD system. I have an `Order` class with two methods: `Purchase` and `Deliver`. These method bodies contain only the code necessary to enforce invariants and raise an event. `Order` has no dependencies. I also have a `DeliveryService` that is invoked when an event is raised. It’s `Ship( orderId, address )` method is what does the work of delivering orders. `DeliveryService` has no dependencies. The loose runtime coupling wiring events to handlers is immaterial to this discussion.

Comment: Your system has one service `DeliveryService`. It’s `Ship(order)` method is coupled to your `Order` struct. If you have extracted any rules into a `DeliveryRules` class it is also coupled to that class. If you haven’t done so, then you are less coupled but will be duplicating rules for the `InternationalDeliveryService` next week. This system is maintainable only if it remains trivial.

Comment: The difference between theses systems is one follows a functional design (DDD) where responsibilities are properly separated and the other does not. By simply moving all invariants into a “rules” class (entity) one can limit the knowledge of each service. Once we have done this we can go one step further and decouple each service from the rules completely by way of events. This is a much more supple design. Now I can have many deliveries all with different rules (because the service does not check any rules) and I don’t have to duplicate the logic that actually does the delivering.

Comment: Maybe a better example would be `EmailService`. If your company sends 50 kinds of emails out to customers, each with its own rules, you would not want 50 services. You only need one service that actually sends an email. You just need 50 ways to invoke it. Either this can be done directly (i.e. coupling) from 50 other services that check invariants and then make the call, or this can be done by 50 methods checking invariants and raising a single event. The latter is *much* simpler.

Comment: ok so you are factually incorrect about the lack of coupleing in your example. If you load Order from the db then you are coupled to the Order struct via the data layer. You are also coupled to Order via the data interface defined in Order.Whatever(parameters required for the service)

Comment: Im not sure your email example is a good one. would you put 50 methods on your Email object? do all the emails require the same underlying data? what rules would you define for an Email? Unless you think that email is a key flaw in ADM lets stick to the ecommerce model

Comment: I also feel that you keeo shying away from the central point. Which is the multiple methods on the Order object. You say there are only 2, but in fact there is one per process. This is the flaw in the classic OOP approach to large systems. DDD doesnt come into it, as we can just give the services 'Domain' style names and say they are the domain objects

Comment: in fact i would go further and say DDD encourages an ADM approach. Although the business will talk about Deliverying or Purchasing an Order actually they tend to treat each process as a completely seperate domain with seperate departments of people assigned to processes. This means only the data is common.

Comment: I did not say that nothing was dependent on `Order`, I said `Order` has no dependencies. I was simply pointing out that my service is not dependent on `Order`, but yours is dependent on the struct. I also pointed out that your services must also either be dependent on other “rule” objects or require duplication. Again, my services don’t require validation concerns. `Email` is a great example. It only needs one method `Send( headers, body)`, not 50. All emails *do* require the same underlying data (e.g. SMTP).

Comment: The rules for the sending/content of an email are specific to the process (`Purchase`/`Deliver`), the but the sending is the same. An ADM would require 50 services to be directly coupled to `EmailService` in order to call `Send` according to the rules of its process. I could synthesize rules for a few processes if that helps your understanding.

Comment: you also said "DeliveryService has no dependencies"

Comment: I fail to see the problem with having multiple methods on `Order`. Like I mentioned above, if it doesn’t make sense `Order` could be split, but having “only the data in common” is a good reason to keep the each method on the same object. Rules often govern how data changes and splitting rules into separate files may mean an invariant may not be enforced (data changes without an invariant defined in another file being checked). At the very least it becomes harder to know what invariants exist for a some data as they are spread out.

Comment: `DeliverService` has no dependencies. It’s method `Ship` requires a scalar `orderId` and scalar `address` string.

Comment: the problem with having a method per process on order is 1. Order becomes literally thousands of lines of code. 2. Every process change changes order. every change to order potentially affects _all_ processes. Bugs get introduced in processes you havent had any change requests for

Comment: if DeliveryService uses the orderid to read an order out the of the db, it has a dependency on Order

Comment: if you are sending an email as part of purchase/deliver then the rules are in the purchase/deliver service. the actual sending of the email is some other service

Comment: It does not need to read `Order` out of the DB. What would it do with it? `Order` has no public fields. Any dependency on the data in `Order` (say it needs `weight`) should be moved “up” into the event making it `Send( orderId, address, weight)`. This allows us to deliver anything as long as it can be identified (maybe `guid` instead of `orderId`), an address and a weight. This is better.

Comment: well before you were saying it would use order id to query. if you are saying now that deliver only requires an id to write to an audit trail or some such and a single address string, then that is an unbelievable over simplification. If you say it needs a DeliverEvent with all the required fields then its tightly coupled to that class and the Order method which populates it.

Comment: I don’t see how it would result in thousands of lines of code. How many ways can we change `Order` state? In any case, a large class isn’t a problem if SOLID design mandates it. I’m sure your editor supports folding. I *want* all of the rules for a given bit of data together. How else can I know what rules exist? Search through dozens of services? Finally (and again), if the rules for the mutation of the data within an object are truly orthogonal (no overlap), the data should be split into more entities. This is called modeling according to behavior and is a cornerstone of DDD.

Comment: You have hundreds of processes that act on order. purchase, deliver, stock management, pre order, a dozen payment methods, fraud checks, refunds, returns. The business invents new ones every day! The fact is that you don't need to know about all these order processes in order to implement one of them. 'invariants' are process dependent. state is process dependent. Order is merely static data. And ADM is the ideal way to model it.

Comment: The goal of SOLID design isn't to remove all coupling (I've said this before). It's to *mange* coupling, and it is accomplished by separating responsibilities. We are going to go with `EmailService` from now on because it's simpler (of course I am not listing all of the data a real delivery may require) and I don't want you to be able to hide behind "that is an oversimplification". Sending an email is different from the rules that apply to it's content/whether it should be sent.

Comment: You just created the nightmare! Calling `EmailService` from `DeliverService`, or more generally coupling services, is *precisely* the web of dependencies that makes a system impossible to understand when it reaches a certain size.

Comment: urg, email service, what does it do? send an email? there are no rules. it accepts an Email object with subject, body etc and sends it. All applications could send emails, how can we have a common idea about the business rules? Why change from order now?

Comment: Invariants are *absolutely not* process dependent. Any rule like "we want all the rules that apply to X plus this one other rule" exemplifies this. When this occurs you must either duplicate or couple. An OOP system does not force you to make that choice because all of the rules are together.

Comment: OK imagine that some of my orders I send to a third party to fulfill. Are you sayign they will have then same 'invarient' rules about orders that I do? why do you think that two processes cant have different rules abotu what makes a valid order?

Comment: Yes `EmailService` sends an email. It does **one** thing. There are rules about sending emails though! When an `Order` is placed, we only send an email if the user opts in at checkout. When a delivery ships, we only send an email if the weight is more than 50 pounds.

Comment: I do not think that two processes can't have different rules. Of course they can. I'm talking about when they overlap. This is incredibly common.

Comment: Ok so those rules go in the objects with the single responsiblity for purchase and delivery accordingly

Comment: the purchase service checks Order.MarketingOptIn. the delivery service checks Order.TotalWeight

Comment: Which objects are those? You have services and a struct? Are you suggesting we couple services to more objects? I have `Order.Purchase` and `Payload.Deliver` to hold those rules and an email service listening for an event should it be raised.

Comment: What is the structure of your event object/objects

Comment: im sticking with the same structure i always have Order (data only)+ services (logic)

Comment: entities (data + business logic) + services (detail logic)

Comment: sure but you need your event object right?

Comment: events (data). I believe we both have events

Comment: nope i just have order

Comment: or rather all my event objects are Order

Comment: "a simple orderEvent table where we write orderId, date, eventType". What is this then?

Comment: I mean we can skip them if you like, but then the only difference is that I have moved the purchase and deliver methods to their own objects. The reason for that becomes obvious when you add the 48 other unrelated reasons to email.

Comment: Thats the audit trail to record the various thigns that happened to order. in this case you would write "order purchase started"," emailed order confirmation" etc etc

Comment: I'm asking about your "The OrderPurchased/Delivered events raised in the process would be consumed by other contexts to actually carry-out the payment/shipment"

Comment: presumably you have a DeliveryEmail event which communicates to the email service the info it needs to send a delivery email?

Comment: You moved them into what amounts to a transaction script. The reason this **fails** becomes obvious when we want to change which `EmailService` we use. How does an `Order` have different data between reads? No I would have an `OrderDelivered` event that is caught by a subscriber which takes necessary action.

Comment: you havent yet explained what the various different email services are supposed to do. As I have the logic in the Delivery/Purchase services I dont see that I need omore than one Emailservice.Send(Email email)

Comment: Order never has differnt data. Once you place your order thats it. its immutable

Comment: We both only have one `EmailService` with one `Send` method. The difference is you have 50 other services coupled to it. More generally speaking though, starting down a road where services are directly coupled is a nightmare. It's not really *about* emails. I'm just illustrating the problem.

Comment: How do you know an order has been purchased? Is that not possible?

Comment: check the audit log to see what processes have been completed on that order

Comment: How can a system of totally "immutable" data *do* anything?

Comment: So the order is different on read because you record events.

Comment: the audit trail isn't part of Order, but OK

Comment: Otherwise you could not enforce "order cannot be delivered if it was not purchased"

Comment: The audit is part of the order if it is material to the order.

Comment: How else could you enforce that invariant above?

Comment: Well you can, by simply not sending orders to the delivery process until after purchasing. But in fact this is very useful. as often you will want to deliver non purchased orders and other exceptional cases. Say for example a customer claims non delivery when all your records show the order was delivered. But they are a good customer and you want them happy

Comment: Also, we should be careful not to confuse the actual code and concepts. Audit trail is NOT part of the Order class

Comment: If the audit trail is used to populate the data in order it is. Period. Changing the audit trail changes the order. They are simply different views of the same thing.

Comment: I'm saying it is _not_ used to populate the data in order

Comment: normally you would neever check the audit trail. if the service picks an order up off the incoming queue then it processes it regardless of what has happened before.

Comment: So your system is predicated on stringing scripts together in the correct order? That is literally insane and completely unnecessary.

Comment: its standard practice in event driven systems

Comment: I've been assuming that you are terming things 'scripts' in a derogatory fashion. The services would usually be stateless micro-services listening to message queues

Comment: Hence no writing back to Order, its a message on a queue and you cant. Obviously you can do the same thing with a database instead of a queue. its just less scaleable

Comment: "stringing scripts together in the correct order" is called "orchestration" when you are a consultant

Comment: Its seem as  a good thing because its super flexible. I invent a new business process i want to apply to UK order just after they are purchased? no probs, just write the service and alter the orchestration accordingly

Comment: No. It is **absolutely not** standard practice to hide business rules in the order scripts get invoked in any system. Event driven systems play perfectly well with DDD because the infrastructure is of orthogonal concern. What you are suggesting is unbelievably fragile, and again, totally unnecessary. What if the data for purchase is material for shipping? "No order can be delivered within 2 days of purchase". That rules is just hanging out somewhere a the top? Rules belong at the bottom!

Comment: although I would be lying if i said its the first time ive heard it been called "literally insane"

Comment: well rules with delays are problematic but not super difficult to solve. Just stick the order into a queue with a 'dont process untill' date

Comment: like i said before though, you are shying away from the problem with your system. a single monolithic order class with rules from dozens of departments and projects with nothing in common except the data structure they require as input

Comment: "scripts" isn't derogatory. It's an accurate assessment of how your system works. It's equally flexible as a DDD system. Should I need a new rule for delivering to "good customers", I can simply add a method with the new rules. They key here is the rule is *part* of the core domain. Not just floating in the service layer/configuration somewhere.

Comment: one does not _simply_ add a method to the Order class. That same class controls all processes in the business? that's being used on hundreds on machines? that has 1000 lines of code and 20 dev teams with 3 feature branches each working on it this week?

Comment: I need you to explain *how* that is a problem. Because the file is large? That's just silly. Do you not have an editor with code folding or an outline view? And as I've beaten to death already, `Order` can be split according to concerns (and should be). If we want `ShoppingCart`, `PurchaseRequest`, `ProductQueue`, and `Payload` according to "shopping", "payment", "inventory", and "shipping" contexts respectively we may do so.

Comment: I'm not married to `Order`. That was just (supposed to be) simple example to illustrate a problem.

Comment: Its a problem because 1. any shared state or logic will cause merge conflicts 2. any change requires you deploy all your systems, even if the change is not applicable to those systems. 3. change requests come from peoepl who only know about a single process and dont want to change other processes.

Comment: It's only a problem if all of the behavior *must* be on a single object. But if all of the behavior must be on a single object... well... it must be. The system mandates it to ensure invariants cannot be bypassed. The other option is duplication or coupling. This suffers from the same or worse problems.

Comment: It's about tradeoffs.

Comment: Your main concern about my system seems to be "the file is too large" where mine is "your system has a web of coupling and/or duplication". Which is worse?

Comment: If you split Order into PurchaseRequest and DeliveryRequest but each has the same fields then they are the same as PurchaseService and DeliveryService. its just semantics as to whether you instantiate new ones for every request or persist them and pass the requests in one at a time.

Comment: No. `Payload` can have both `Deliver` and `DeliverInternational` (or whatever other state changes may occur to the payload).

Comment: Your objection is worse. but untrue.

Comment: also i think you mis-characterise my objection.

Comment: well then you have the problem of what populates the differnet requests

Comment: and wehat tyou do when you require a new field on a request

Comment: It is true though. You said above that your services will call `EmailService`. I can copy and paste that here if you wish. You **also** said you would prefer to duplicate for `Deliver`/`DeliverInternational`. I can copy and paste that as well.

Comment: true, but whats your point?

Comment: Well, calling one service from another creates a web of coupling. There is no way to know which services will be coupled to which other services. When it's just the 2-3 it may seem like no big deal, but when it's 20-100 we have a problem. Duplicating the `Deliver` logic in `DeliverInternational` is duplication. Again when it's just once or twice no big deal, but when the system does this too much it becomes difficult to change.

Comment: What do you mean by "new field on request"? Like I need `weight`? You change the system to account for it. It's not like this is unique to a DDD system.

Comment: well if i scroll up ... "the list of things your purchased to put on the receipt"

Comment: calling the email service from the delivery and purchase services couples them to the email service yes. But crucially it doesn't couple them to each other.

Comment: Having an Order class with Purchase() and Deliver() methods on it couples the purchase and delivery processes together in the tightest possible manner.

Comment: Duplicating logic from Deliver in International Delivery is bad from a programming perspective, but good when the requirements for the two process only happen to over lap at this point in time. Rather than being inextricably linked. My preference for the duplication is merely down to my experience that the former is more usual than the later,

Comment: Both your rebuttal to the service web and deliver duplication are predicated on these being the only instances where this occurs. You are essentially saying, "It's not so bad". We have a system with like 4 objects and we *already* have 2 extra bit of coupling and 1 source of duplication. These problems will manifest dozens of times over in many different ways as a system grows and changes.

Comment: but you _dont_ have extra coupling. you have _less_ coupling

Comment: You must be misunderstanding "coupling". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming) Specifically read the "Procedural Programming" section as an ADM + Services exhibits many of these.

Comment: and as i say the duplication is purely a matter of prefernce. totoaly up to you

Comment: I cannot stress this enough. The goal is **NOT** less coupling. It's **MANAGING** coupling. A "web" of coupling is not a form of the latter.

Comment: Then click on the "functional design" link under "Solutions" as it pretty much outlines exactly what I'm attempting to convey to you. We don't want to deliver *and* email in a single module for example.

Comment: We can achieve SRP by simply raising an event notifying that an "order has been delivered" and having two services take action independently.

Comment: I assure you i fully understand coupling. and admit that you are correct in that coupling does exist in the ADM approach. My assertion is that there is MORE coupling in the classic OOP approach. Specifically your services are coupled to Order via your Event structs and your methods are coupled by virtue of being in the _exact same class_ and operating on the same data despite being unconnected

Comment: you can't achieve SRP while order contains logic from multiple unrelated processes.

Comment: Hence you have a chain of coupling from serviceA up via uits event to Order, across to the method associated with serviceB, down through its event to service B

Comment: Now I can change _part_ of service B's logic without affecting A, but as soon as I touch the event or the part of the logic in Order I have a problem

Comment: The solution? include all the _data_ in all events, and move _all_ the logic into the services. Now my only coupling between services is if the Order data schema it self changes.

Comment: I *want* my methods coupled. **IF** they are indeed in the same object, then they have been *specifically* modeled to be there because the data each method acts upon contains relevant invariants that are material to the process. The very premise of DDD is to organize business rules. Therefore, I want them all in one place where they are easy to see and reason about.

Comment: The coupling you are describing is managed. It is linear and easy to reason about. We have `Entity -> Event <- Service(n)`.

Comment: It's trivial to find which services subscribe to which events. It's trivial to find which methods raise events. It's trivial to know where business logic needs to be changed when we change how `Deliver` works without forgetting to update `DeliverInternational`. This system is easy to change.

Comment: The only part of the above that can't be ctrl + F is knowing where to change business rules. But if the system is designed according to our UL, everyone will know that `Order.Deliver` is where the rules live.

Comment: You contradict yourself. DO you want only business rules which are related on a single object, or do you want all business rules in one place?

Comment: its not easy to change. Ease isnt about you being able to find the code you need to change. its about being able to deploy it without touching any other processes. In your system. The Order class has logic which is used in more than one process. If you change one processes method and deploy it, then code in those other methods are now running your newly deployed Order class. You have changed them and potentially introduced bugs or unforseen consequences

Comment: Ease of change is has nothing to do with deployment. Deployment is an entirely different concern, and can be difficult in any complex system with lots of modules. You seem to be suggesting that the problem is that this system cannot be "hotfixed" easily. You are stretching now. That is not worse than a web of coupling and duplication - Which are the *quintessential* examples of what not to do in a software system.

Comment: My opinions are not radical here. What I am suggesting has been the dominant paradigm for quite some time now. There is a reason transaction script based systems fell out of fashion 20 years ago. Because they don't make the software easy to maintain. Plain and simple. Slapping in some events and wrapping scripts in "services" doesn't really change anything.

Comment: TS systems can work. I have personally designed such systems! When the use-case is rather trivial or the developers are not suited for domain modeling, such systems can be pragmatic. People think is scripts. That's how we work, so it is easy to bring on junior devs and get them up and running. But I cannot recommend such a system as a general starting point in a DDD question thread.

Comment: Your suggestion cettainly isnt radical. Its old fashioned monolithic OOP architecture. What you call a web of transaction scripts is modern distributed microservice architecture. Anyway, I feel that I have convinced you and that you will try ADM out in your next project

Comment: DDD is a *design* methodology. Whether a system is a monolith or microservices is an *architectural* consideration orthogonal in nature. DDD plays well with either. Fair enough though. I wish you good luck!